# SDL Fredhopper indexer and query published items sync issue

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper, 2013-sp1

We have integrated smart target module to one of client. Now we have a issue with fredhopper indexer is not sync with query server.

SDL Version: SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Smart target version: 2014 SP1

Fredhopper version: fredhopper-7.5-revision-15

```
Topology.txt
# instance name | host | preset | indexer |  comment
indexer|localhost|1|-|Indexer for staging environment

query|localhost|2|indexer|Query server for staging environment
```

Issue:

We have found discrepancies between the Indexer and the query server. Meaning, the banner DCP component is successfully published and indexed but is not synced with the query server.

**Indexer URL**:
http://localhost:8180/preview/?fh_location=//catalog01/en_US&preview_seo=false

Total : **383 Items**

Searched by published banner dcp component item id : **198118**

Results by pass ID (3) :

3 Items: Matched items displayed correctly

**Query URL**:
http://localhost:9180/preview/?fh_location=//catalog01/en_US&

Total : **383 Items**

Searched by published banner dcp component item id : **198118**

Results by pass ID (3) :

3 Items: Matched but not displayed items in the search area

Kindly advise us to resolve this issue.

Comment: I don't see the discrepancy in your numbers. Did you paste correctly?

Comment: Counts are coming correctly but the issue was indexed xml are not synced      with qserver. when we search by particular item id on query server in the search results not coming that item..

Answer (score 3):

It looks like indeed parts of the index are not synced properly.

Probably your best course of action: start with the log files from the "query" instance (`fredhopper.log` and `syncclient.log`), and then correlate the events in those with the "indexer" instance (`syncserver.log`, `searchindexer.log`, `treebuilder.catalog01.log`, `xmlloader.log`).

Also verify that all of these processes are actually running.

Comment: This issue seems to something wrong on fredhopper, we raised the ticket with SDL support, issue under investigation. 

If you run the manual re-index command bin\fresh-index-to-live indexer then it's getting sync.. seems to be some bug on fredhopper itemstore... will update you once SDL come back with solutions